# CS50 readability expected EOF, not " "

Tags: c, cs50, eof

I'm trying to check the readability problem from CS50 2022 and all the manual test I do my code works but when I try to run the cs50check I get all "expected EOF, not " " " message for all the functions and I don't understand where this " " comes from. Can someone help me ?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters (string text);
int count_words (string text);
int count_sentences (string text);
int index (float calculate_float);

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt user for the text to analyse
    string text = get_string ("Text to analyse : ");

    // Count letters, worlds and sentences in the text
    int letters = count_letters (text);
    int words = count_words (text);
    int sentences = count_sentences (text);

    //  Calculate the Coleman-Liau index
    float calculate_float = (0.0588 * letters / words * 100 - 0.296 * sentences / words * 100 - 15.8);
    int index = round(calculate_float);

    if ( index < 1)
    {
        printf ("Before Grade 1\n ");
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( index >= 16)
    {
        printf ("Grade 16+\n ");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Grade %i\n ", index);
    }
}

// Count number of letters in the text
int count_letters (string text)
{
    int letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < strlen(text) ; i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z') || (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')) letters++;
    }
    return letters;
}

// Count number of words in the text
int count_words (string text)
{
    int words = 1;
    for (int j = 0 ; j < strlen(text) ; j++)
    {
        if (text[j] == (' ')) words++ ;
    }
    return words;
}

// Count sentences in the text
int count_sentences (string text)
{
    int sentences = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(text); k++)
    {
        if ((text [k] == ('.')) || (text [k] == ('!')) || (text [k] == ('?'))) sentences++ ;
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your input !

Comment: I can't tell the big-picture problem, but I notice spaces after newlines in the various `printf()` calls: these spaces are probably unnecessary and maybe even unhelpful. e.g `"Before Grade 1\n "`  could be `"Before Grade 1\n"` (space removed after newline).

Comment: Oh wahou thank you so much, that was actually it ! everything works fine !

Comment: Use `isalpha((unsigned char)text[i])` instead of comparing with AZaz.

Comment: Minor: `0.0588 * letters / words * 100 - 0.296 * sentences / words * 100 - 15.8` uses `double` constants and has a `double` result which is then saved as a `float`.  The `int index = round(calculate_float);` takes that `float`, convert to a `double`, calls `round()` and converted that `double` to an `int`.  Rather than mess with all that converting down to `float` and then back up to `double`, use `double calculate_float` and `lround()` instead of `round()`.